# TOR 6.0 no longer opens from flash drive

Tags: configuration

I've always launched TOR from a password protected flash drive, (many years).  Version 6.0 gives an error message that path is unavailable and I may not have permission to this file. I am administrator and also manually check administrator box in TOR.  TOR 6.0 runs perfectly from desktop.  I did a clean install on Windows7X64 this week but have been running this setup for many years and the flash always worked.  Any ideas?

Comment: Being an administrator doesn't mean that you will have permissions, it just means that if you wanted to you could assign yourself the permissions. You should also *never* run desktop software like a web browser as an administrator. It is not required and it is *dangerous*. You should check the path does provide the correct permissions (and consider setting them to be for a normal user account to use instead and run it as a non-administrator)